# Is it possible to play completely legato 5 finger legato at a very high tempo?

Tags: piano

To clarify what I mean here is a picture of the perfect legato I have in question on the right, vs. the slurred or legatissimo(?) touch that is on the left.

The tempo in mind is 192 BPM. Each note played would be a 16th note.

I am asking because I am a beginner and I want to know if such a thing is even possible or should be attempted

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is certainly possible to play "live" 16th notes at 192 BPM, but I wouldn't recommend it as an exercise for a beginner, and many keyboard players will never ever play as fast as that (and never want to, either).

At that speed, there is no practical distinction between legato and legatissimo, and staccato would be impossible anyway.

On an acoustic piano, you can't "pull the keys back up" as fast as you like in the same way that you can push them down, and you can remove your fingers from the keys faster than the piano action responds by raising the key and lowering the damper. Even when the damper is down, it takes time for the note to actually stop sounding. For the lowest notes on the piano, that can be a significant fraction of a second.

Just to prove it *is* possible, a Czerny study, Op. 740 No. 13 ...

.

Of course you can create a sound electronically that *does* start and stop "instantaneously", and play it with MIDI to any accuracy you want. That's a perfectly valid thing to do if it creates the sound you want, but it's not very clear from your question what you *really* want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

At that tempo each of those notes is about 78 milliseconds (60 seconds per minute / 192 beats per minute / 4 sixteenths per beat =~ .078) long, so the difference between the release times on the left and on the right is maybe 30ms or so?  That's not much, though it could be enough to be noticeable.  A piano sound doesn't actually cut off instantaneously, which may make slight differences in release times less noticeable.  Hard to say.

But I'm not sure what you're trying to do here.  Is that you're doing a midi recording of your playing and trying to decide whether your playing is technically good enough?  I think it's more important to use your ears.  Can you hear the difference between the left- and right- hand examples?  If you record your playing, does it have the musical effect that you want, or does it sound uneven?  The goal in the end is to be musical.

If your playing sounds uneven and you're trying to use midi data to diagnose why, you might also want to look at the note velocities.

Comment: That exactly is what I'm trying to do, I am also using my ears, and I appreciate the advice about using my ears and for the end result being musical. But I was also wondering about the technical limitations of the instrument at that tempo, your & alpephzero's answers cleared that up. Thanks!